# Concatenate Json strings

Tags: javascript, json

I need to concatenate two Json strings. The code for the first one is below.

```
var output = {
    Studios: $('#btnStudios button').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get(),
    Platform: $('#btnplatforms button').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get(),
    VODEST: $('#btnvodest button').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get(),
    SDHD: $('#btnsdhd button').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get(),
    Category: $('#btncategory button').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get(),
    Genre: $('#btngenre button').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get(),
};
$('.list').html(JSON.stringify(output));
```

And the result is:

```
{"Studios":["warner","tf1","gaumont","pathe","studiocanal","francetv","m6snd"],"Platform":["orange","itunes","sfr"],"VODEST":["vod","est"],"SDHD":["sd","hd"],"Category":["film","tv","others"],"Genre":["thriller","action","drama","horror"]}
```

I need to add this string to it:

```
var per = {Period: {"From":["W6"],"To":["W18"]}}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you sure that is the result? It is not valid JSON.

Comment: How do you want the result to look like?

Comment: *"I need to add this string to it:"* - thats not a string, its another javascript object!

Comment: The first string yes. The second string i am not sure about(The one wich i want to add to the first one). You could correct me if there is any error. @Kobi

Comment: I need to add the new object to the availaible string. Does this sound OK? @Jamiec

Comment: No, it still makes no sense. You're not dealing with strings (until you call `stringify` that is) you're dealing with javascript objects

Comment: The result would look like: {"Studios":["warner","tf1","gaumont","pathe","studiocanal","francetv","m6snd"],"Platform":["orange","itunes","sfr"],"VODEST":["vod","est"],"SDHD":["sd","hd"],"Category":["film","tv","others"],"Genre":["thriller","action","drama","horror"],"Period":{"From":["W6"],"To":["W18"]}} @Filype

Comment: I am not sure if I use the right terminologies. However the end result would look like the above comment @Jamiec

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. On the first string you have `{"Studios["`, it should be `{"Studios":["`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

```
$.extend(output, per);
```

before you call `JSON.stringify(output)`.

This will copy all properties from `per` to `output`.

You can also do that manually:

```
output.Period = per.Period;
```

There is no reason to work with strings here - you can manipulate the JavaScript object, and convert them to a JSON string when you're done. If you do have a string, you can always parse it to an object using:

```
var output = JSON.parse(firstString);
```

But again, you could have done that better.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the first part assumes you're using jQuery (not tagged in original question).

Comment: @Jamiec - You are right. I'm sure `$('#btnStudios button').map().get()` is jQuery, but I am assuming.

Comment: Ha, didnt notice that. I think we can safely assume the OP *should* have been tagged jQuery

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much. String,Array,Object very confusing. Need to work harder :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a new object and add a property to store the data you need?

```
var per = {Period: {"From":["W6"],"To":["W18"]}};
per.output = output;
$('.list').html(JSON.stringify(per));
```